# loc fails on a DataFrame using the DataFrame's own index?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with a DateTime index where there are many duplicate index labels (i.e. rows with the same datetime). I want to look at rows with the same datetime. So I have the following

```
utimes = pd.unique(data.index.tolist())
for time in utimes:
    data_now = data.loc[time]
    # Do some processing on the data_now
```

This fails with an example error: KeyError 'the label [2015-02-05 21:54:00+00:00] is not in the [index]'

Just to check that this isn't an issue in the creation of utimes, this fails

```
data.loc[data.index[0]]
```

with the same error message. How can this be? Here's what the index looks like

```
> data.index
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2015-02-05 21:54:00+00:00, ..., 2015-02-05 23:24:00+00:00]  
Length: 457, Freq: None, Timezone: UTC
```

and

```
> data.index[0]
Timestamp('2015-02-05 22:24:00+0000', tz='UTC')
```

Any ideas why I can't use .loc with a data_frame's own index??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `pd.unique` does not respect the `datetime64` dtype:

```
In [11]: df.index
Out[11]:
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2015-02-05 22:24:00+00:00]
Length: 1, Freq: None, Timezone: UTC

In [12]: pd.unique(df.index)
Out[12]: array([1423175040000000000L], dtype=object)
```

For now (until this bug is fixed in pandas) you can wrap this in a `to_datetime` call:

```
In [13]: pd.to_datetime(pd.unique(df.index))
Out[13]:
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2015-02-05 22:24:00]
Length: 1, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

or, more cleanly, you can use the unique method DatetimeIndex:

```
In [14]: df.index.unique()
Out[14]:
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2015-02-05 22:24:00+00:00]
Length: 1, Freq: None, Timezone: UTC
```

Comment: Great thanks, at least I know I'm not completely crazy.